# JavaScript create box with emails from array

Tags: javascript

I have code like this:

```
function getEmails() {
    var search_in = document.body.innerHTML;
    string_context = search_in.toString();
    emails = string_context.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
    for(var i=0; i<emails.length; i++){
        console.log(emails[i]); 
    }
}
```

Instead of console.log, I need a box to appear with the list of emails from this array and a checkbox next to every email (checkbox is checked by default) and a button `Save`.
When I click the `Save` button, all selected emails should be saved to a txt file.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're practically there,  I suggest your create an element in the markup and then create a string you'll append to it later, for example :

```
var string='';
for(var i=0; i<emails.length; i++){
string += "<div><input type='checkbox'>" +emails[i]+ "</div>"; 
}
```

and when you're done with your string, you can append it to the element of choice in the markup.

Comment: Was going to suggest same. +1

Comment: Ok I think I get it, and what about Save button ?

Comment: I did forget about that save button :) You can add a <button> element in the string aswell, Saving it to .txt. is a bit too broad of a question, basically I suggest you read on how to generate txt files in javascript and how to download them to the computer, Do some research it'll pay off :)